# Matching time slots

Tags: algorithm

I have the following use case: A number of clients want an appointment at a single service provider. Each client reports a number of different time slots in which they would be available. I am looking for an algorithm that would match the time slots of the clients to the available time slots of the service provider with the goal that as many clients as possible have a time slot that works for them. Only one client can see the service provider at the same time.

What would be a good logic for the algorithm?

Side note: I intend to use PHP, but I am just looking for the logic, not the code.

Comment: To clarify : a single provider, and each client needs only a single timeslot? The "weekly" part worries me, it suggests hidden complexity. With the basic description, the problem is equivalent to just finding the maximum number of timeslots in which the provider is busy.

Comment: The problem can be solved as a [max flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem).

Comment: @MSalters Correct, a single provider and each client only needs a single time slot. 
Please ignore weekly. It should not add complexity. The algorithm should generate only one schedule.

Comment: How often does each client interact with the service provider? Do they need final appointments at once? Or after the service provider also got the availability of other clients? Can the appointments change later on? Is there knowledge, which timeslots usually are requested more often? Or which pairs of timeslots are typically both feasable for clients, e.g. consecutive ones, or the same day at different days. That would help for strategies like keeping certain times free at at least one day per week.